# How to fix inconsistent height of HTML5 input boxes?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html-input

Some new input types introduced in HTML5 such as `<input type="date">` are taller in Google Chrome. Is there a way to fix the inconsistent height without setting fixed height?

The goal is making all input types listed below including the submit button to all have the same height. Reasons:

- Match the design especially when they are laid out horizontally.
- Flexibility, when I need some of input boxes to have larger font size.

```js
$("input").each(function() {
  h = $(this).outerHeight();
  $(this).parent().append(h);
});
```

```css
input {
  font: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin: 0;
}

[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
}

button,
[type="button"],
[type="reset"],
[type="submit"] {
  background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Input Heights</h1>
<p><input type="text" placeholder="text"></p>
<p><input type="search" placeholder="search"></p>
<p><input type="tel" placeholder="tel"></p>
<p><input type="url" placeholder="url"></p>
<p><input type="email" placeholder="email"></p>
<p><input type="datetime" placeholder="datetime"></p>
<p><input type="date" placeholder="date"></p>
<p><input type="month" placeholder="month"></p>
<p><input type="week" placeholder="week"></p>
<p><input type="time" placeholder="time"></p>
<p><input type="datetime-local" placeholder="datetime-local"></p>
<p><input type="number" placeholder="number"></p>
<!-- <p><input type="range" placeholder="range"></p> -->
<!-- <p><input type="color" placeholder="color"></p> -->
<p><input type="submit" value="submit"></p>
```

Comment: How about `min-height:1em; max-height:1em;`, or is that cheating?

Comment: Specify the height and padding for the input element to make them all have the same height

Comment: `input[type='date'] {padding-top:4px;}`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue seems to be related to the arrows added by Chrome to the date input:

[image]

These arrows are taller than the text making the whole input taller than the other. They are also treated like text so they are affected by `font-size` and `line-height` which make it a bit tricky.

An idea is to apply a `min-height` to the content area of all the inputs in order to match the height of these arrows. After few tests, we can have equal height if we set `min-height:1.5em` and make `box-sizing:content-box`. The use of `content-box` will make sure the height won't shrink for the other inputs.

```js
$("input").each(function() {
  h = $(this).outerHeight();
  $(this).parent().append(h);
});
```

```css
input {
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin: 0;
  display:inline-block;
  min-height: 1.5em;
  box-sizing:content-box;
}

[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
}

button,
[type="button"],
[type="reset"],
[type="submit"] {
  background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Input Heights</h1>
<p><input type="text" placeholder="text"></p>
<p><input type="search" placeholder="search"></p>
<p><input type="tel" placeholder="tel"></p>
<p><input type="url" placeholder="url"></p>
<p><input type="email" placeholder="email"></p>
<p><input type="datetime" placeholder="datetime"></p>
<p><input type="date" placeholder="date"></p>
<p><input type="month" placeholder="month"></p>
<p><input type="week" placeholder="week"></p>
<p><input type="time" placeholder="time"></p>
<p><input type="datetime-local" placeholder="datetime-local"></p>
<p><input type="number" placeholder="number"></p>
<!-- <p><input type="range" placeholder="range"></p> -->
<!-- <p><input type="color" placeholder="color"></p> -->
<p><input type="submit" value="submit"></p>
```

We can then adjust `padding`, `font-size`, `height` etc and they will always keep the same height:

```css
input {
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin: 0;
  display:inline-block;
  min-height: 1.5em;
  box-sizing:content-box;
}
.big input{
   padding:20px;
}
.small input{
   padding:2px;
}
.h-big input{
   height:50px;
}
.h-small input{
   height:10px;
}
```

```html
<p><input type="text" placeholder="text"><input type="date" placeholder="date"></p>
<p style="font-size:25px;"><input type="text" placeholder="text"><input type="date" placeholder="date"></p>
<p style="font-size:10px;"><input type="text" placeholder="text"><input type="date" placeholder="date"></p>

<p class="big"><input type="text" placeholder="text"><input type="date" placeholder="date"></p>
<p class="small"><input type="text" placeholder="text"><input type="date" placeholder="date"></p>

<p class="h-big"><input type="text" placeholder="text"><input type="date" placeholder="date"></p>
<p class="h-small"><input type="text" placeholder="text"><input type="date" placeholder="date"></p>
```

Comment: Looks promising, I wonder if we can keep the border-box, seems to be ok.

Comment: @Stickers we can keep it but it will fail in some cases .. try to put in the examples of the second snippet and you will see ... with border-box we have to change the min-height value to always have the same height.

Comment: It will make other things very complicated without border-box. I guess it's simply not possible, yours is already very close. Let's wait and see.

Comment: @Stickers with border-box we have to always adjust the min-height which is also complicated in some case. We may probably introduce CSS variable and some complexe calculation with `calc` but not sure if it worth doing it ... for the downvotes, they are probably for the initial question where it's not clear that you are targeting Chrome, So the FF users don't see any issue.

Answer (score 2):

As MrLister pointed out, `max-height` and `min-height`, expressed in `em`, seems to be your best bet. I use it frequently on production systems and haven't had any complaints:

```js
function updateInputs() {
  $("input").each(function() {
    $('span', $(this).parent()).remove();
    $('<span />', {
      text: $(this).outerHeight()
    }).appendTo($(this).parent())
  });
}
$('#fontSizer').on('input', function() {
  $('body').css('font-size', $(this).val() + 'px');
  updateInputs();
});
$(window).on('load',updateInputs);
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px
}

input {
  font: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin: 0;
  max-height: 2.25em;
  min-height: 2.25em;
}

[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
}

button,
[type="button"],
[type="reset"],
[type="submit"] {
  background-color: silver;
}

.fixed-top {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .85);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Input Heights</h1>
<p><input type="text" placeholder="text"></p>
<p><input type="search" placeholder="search"></p>
<p><input type="tel" placeholder="tel"></p>
<p><input type="url" placeholder="url"></p>
<p><input type="email" placeholder="email"></p>
<p><input type="datetime" placeholder="datetime"></p>
<p><input type="date" placeholder="date"></p>
<p><input type="month" placeholder="month"></p>
<p><input type="week" placeholder="week"></p>
<p><input type="time" placeholder="time"></p>
<p><input type="datetime-local" placeholder="datetime-local"></p>
<p><input type="number" placeholder="number"></p>
<!-- <p><input type="range" placeholder="range"></p> -->
<!-- <p><input type="color" placeholder="color"></p> -->
<p><input type="submit" value="submit"></p>

<div class="fixed-top">
  <input type="range" step="0.01" id="fontSizer" max="54" min="10" value="16">
</div>
```

Note the range slider only changes the `font-size` on `<body>` (and updates the size displayed, accordingly).

---

A completely different approach is to increase the padding value for the normal ones so they reach the same size as the ones having spinners. The closest I got to something decent is

```
:root {
  --input-padding: 0.5rem;
}
input {
  padding: calc(var(--input-padding) + .1475em) var(--input-padding);
  line-height: 1.225em
}
input[type="date" i], input[type="datetime-local" i], input[type="month" i], input[type="time" i], input[type="week" i] {
  padding: var(--input-padding)
}
```

```js
function updateInputs() {
  $("input").each(function() {
    $('span', $(this).parent()).remove();
    $('<span />', {
      text: $(this).outerHeight()
    }).appendTo($(this).parent())
  });
}
$('#fontSizer').on('input', function() {
  $('body').css('font-size', $(this).val() + 'px');
  updateInputs();
});
$(window).on('load',updateInputs);
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px
}
input {
  font: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  margin: 0;
}

[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
}

button,
[type="button"],
[type="reset"],
[type="submit"] {
  background-color: silver;
}

.fixed-top {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .85);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
}
:root {
  --input-padding: 0.5rem;
}
input {
  padding: calc(var(--input-padding) + .1475em) var(--input-padding);
  line-height: 1.225em
}
input[type="date" i], input[type="datetime-local" i], input[type="month" i], input[type="time" i], input[type="week" i] {
  padding: var(--input-padding)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Input Heights</h1>
<p><input type="text" placeholder="text"></p>
<p><input type="search" placeholder="search"></p>
<p><input type="tel" placeholder="tel"></p>
<p><input type="url" placeholder="url"></p>
<p><input type="email" placeholder="email"></p>
<p><input type="datetime" placeholder="datetime"></p>
<p><input type="date" placeholder="date"></p>
<p><input type="month" placeholder="month"></p>
<p><input type="week" placeholder="week"></p>
<p><input type="time" placeholder="time"></p>
<p><input type="datetime-local" placeholder="datetime-local"></p>
<p><input type="number" placeholder="number"></p>
<!-- <p><input type="range" placeholder="range"></p> -->
<!-- <p><input type="color" placeholder="color"></p> -->
<p><input type="submit" value="submit"></p>

<div class="fixed-top">
  <input type="range" step="0.01" id="fontSizer" max="54" min="10" value="16">
</div>
```

However, it's not perfect. The errors are not linear and I suspect there's some rounding involved. Sometimes it goes above, sometimes below.

Comment: two small issues: the alignment of the arrows added by chrome are messed and when we want to add padding the content height will become *technically* 0 (visually it's not an issue btw)

Comment: The alignment of the arrows is a completely different issue, @Temani. It's not fixed by Chrome themselves. How and why should i fix it in this answer? The question states clearly: equal heights on all inputs. Which is all my answer is about. Placement of spinners can be fixed by hiding them cross browser and drawing your own. They are drawn [quite differently](https://css-tricks.com/numeric-inputs-a-comparison-of-browser-defaults/) in different browsers.

Comment: the alignment was fine before you apply the max-height, that's why I commented .. I am not discussing a previous issue not fixed but an issue that appear in your code.

Comment: @Temani, you're right. Luckily, most web pages use one size for all inputs, so the alignment can be fixed for that size alone.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the line height:

```css
input {
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: 22px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<input type="date">
```

Comment: It stops working as as soon as you apply some padding to the input.

Answer (score 1):

Define height (and padding) in `em` unit, in this case input height will follow font size

```js
$("input").each(function() {
  var span = $('<span>');
  $(this).parent().append(span);
  setInterval(() => span.text($(this).outerHeight()), 100);
});
$('#button').on('click', function(){
  $('form').css('font-size', 10 + Math.random() * 15);
});
```

```css
input {
  font: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  margin: 0;

  padding: 0.5em;
  height: 2.5em;
}

[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
}

button,
[type="button"],
[type="reset"],
[type="submit"] {
  background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Input Heights</h1>
<button id="button">change font size</button>
<form>
<p><input type="text" placeholder="text"></p>
<p><input type="search" placeholder="search"></p>
<p><input type="tel" placeholder="tel"></p>
<p><input type="url" placeholder="url"></p>
<p><input type="email" placeholder="email"></p>
<p><input type="datetime" placeholder="datetime"></p>
<p><input type="date" placeholder="date"></p>
<p><input type="month" placeholder="month"></p>
<p><input type="week" placeholder="week"></p>
<p><input type="time" placeholder="time"></p>
<p><input type="datetime-local" placeholder="datetime-local"></p>
<p><input type="number" placeholder="number"></p>
<!-- <p><input type="range" placeholder="range"></p> -->
<!-- <p><input type="color" placeholder="color"></p> -->
<p><input type="submit" value="submit"></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

This work for me:

```css
input {
  height:100%
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<input type="date">
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove any vertical padding and add `max-height` Then replace the vertical padding with `line-height` (make sure to specify units, blank is a percentage).

All this combined with the `box-sizing: border-box` will fix most of the inputs.

Now, the input type submit and a real `<button>` are the only problem. The text is vertically aligned to the bottom. I can't seem to get that changed. I believe its an issue with default browser styling on those elements BUT `appearance: none` doesn't appear to help.

Perhaps someone can improve on this?

```js
$("input").each(function() {
  h = $(this).outerHeight();
  $(this).parent().append(h);
});
```

```css
input, button {
  font: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 50px;
  max-height: 36px;
}

[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
}

button,
[type="button"],
[type="reset"],
[type="submit"] {
  background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Input Heights</h1>
<p><input type="text" placeholder="text"></p>
<p><input type="search" placeholder="search"></p>
<p><input type="tel" placeholder="tel"></p>
<p><input type="url" placeholder="url"></p>
<p><input type="email" placeholder="email"></p>
<p><input type="datetime" placeholder="datetime"></p>
<p><input type="date" placeholder="date"></p>
<p><input type="month" placeholder="month"></p>
<p><input type="week" placeholder="week"></p>
<p><input type="time" placeholder="time"></p>
<p><input type="datetime-local" placeholder="datetime-local"></p>
<p><input type="number" placeholder="number"></p>
<!-- <p><input type="range" placeholder="range"></p> -->
<!-- <p><input type="color" placeholder="color"></p> -->
<p><input type="submit" value="submit"></p>
<p><button>submit</button>
```

Comment: The point here is to allow various font sizes and all inputs to have same height, while having the native spinner buttons centered vertically. `px` won't get you too far on this one.

Comment: Look at the code. It's using variable font sizes. the pixel setting is to force a line-height AND container height. Those allow the box to stay fixed as you requested

Comment: Place `body {font-size: 60px}` in your CSS and see what happens.

Answer (score -1):

You need to not only set the element height but also the font-size

```
input{
    height: 1em;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-size-adjust: 1;
    padding-top: 0.1em;
    padding-bottom: 0.1em;
}
```

Example fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/rahulsalvi2k7/50otuem2/